# node js security issue

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

i am trying to create authentication with node js and i notice that if i console log req.body it shows the password after submission.is there any way to prevent this?or maybe i'm doing something wrong?here is a sample of my code:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);
console.log(req.body)
var user = new models.User({
username:  req.body.username,
email:      req.body.email,
password:   hash,
password2: req.body.password2
});
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2','not match').equals(req.body.password);
user.save(function(err,user) {
...
```

Comment: No? If you send something to the server as text, then print it to the console, it'l be in plain text. I guess you could... not console.log passwords?

Comment: plus... heh, why are you storing password2 as plain text in the database? kinda defeats the purpose of hashing doesn't it?

Comment: yep you are right.i forgot hashing it..this is for test  not a real site.i ;m new to node js.and i was wondering if there is a way to hash password on server side too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not to store plain text passwords in your models or your database. **Ever**.

Comment: i forgot to hash password2 but my qustion was if there is way to hash password before sending on server

Comment: @thomasg That will depend on the framework you're using, but I'd recommend hashing it yourself until then. Why do you need to store the hashed password twice? You can just check if the hashes of both inputs match, then store the single hash, and return an error if they don't match.

Comment: my question is not about how to save on db.but if i console.log the req body it will give evey password.and i was wondering if we can hash password so even if someone console log req body it will appear hash and not plain text.

Comment: No, if you `console.log` it, it will log whatever is set on the object, hashed or otherwise. Hash it before your store it like you are with `password`, and you'll find that `password2` is redundant, because if the passwords match then they will be the same hash.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to create new hash variable.
- If you need the password can be hashed after use `bcrypt.hashSync` so you can try this one:

  ```
  router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    // --------
    req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);
    // --------
    console.log(req.body);
    var user = new models.User({
      username:  req.body.username,
      email:      req.body.email,
      password:   req.body.password,
      password2: req.body.password2
    }); 
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2','not match').equals(req.body.password);
    user.save(function(err,user) {
      ...
  ```